# Create Uri to file, bit it's cannot submit the data

Tags: android, file-upload, uri

Create Uri to file, bit it's cannot submit the data

I use this mehtods

```
if(requestCode == VIDEO){
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                previewImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                contentURI = data.getData();
                videoPath = getPath(getApplicationContext(),contentURI);
                Glide.with(this).load(contentURI).into(previewImageView);
                video.setVideoURI(contentURI);
                video.requestFocus();
                //video.start();
                MediaController mc= new MediaController(UploadActivity.this);
                video.setMediaController(mc);
                check_video = "ok";
            }

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

I can got the uri value

like

content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D135

then when use click the submit the data, I got the error code.

```
File videofile = new File(contentURI.getPath());
                        Uri videouri = Uri.fromFile(videofile);
                        uploadFile(videouri);

private void uploadFile(Uri videoPath) {

            // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
            Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            File file = new File(videoPath);
            // Parsing any Media type file
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestBody);
            ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getApiClient().create(ApiConfig.class);
            Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.upload("token", map);
```

the erroe code is

problem uploading video file:/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%sD135(No such file or dirertory)

Comment: Do you want to upload video or just select video and get its path

Comment: @SarveshHon Hon  I want to upload the video when user click submit button. So when user clikc submit button it will execute uploadFile() process.

Comment: Use the full uri to upload your file. Not the path part of it. And do not use the File class.